# PDF to PNG with ImageMagick/GhostScript: Colorspace=sRGB breaks script

Tags: images, imagemagick, ghostscript, image-processing

In order to convert a PDF with 100 pages to single PNG files, I've been using the following command:

```
C:\Program files\ImageMagick\convert -density 150 -alpha Opaque file.pdf file.png
```

But that resulted in PNGs that were over-saturated. This is why I modified the command to the following one, adding the `colorspace` parameter:

```
C:\Program files\ImageMagick\convert -colorspace sRGB -density 150 -alpha Opaque file.pdf file.png
```

The colors look good now. However, only the first page of the PDF is converted now, all others are just dropped. Why? Is the order of the arguments wrong? I've tested different orders but none with success.

However, accessing the subsequent pages directly (via `file.pdf[1]` etc.) works. But why doesn't it convert the full document in batch anymore?

**ImageMagick version info:**

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.1-9 2013-01-04 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib freetype jp2 jpeg lcms lzma ps tiff x xml zlib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following little workaround to solve the problem, but I don't like it, obviously:

```
for /L %%p in (1,1,100) do C:\ImageMagick\convert -colorspace sRGB -density 150 -alpha Opaque file.pdf[%%p] file-%%p.png
```

**Edit: There's a better solution as well:**

1. In ImageMagick's `delegates.xml`, in section `<delegate decode="ps:alpha"` replace `sDEVICE=pngalpha` by `sDEVICE=pnmraw`
2. Use `C:\ImageMagick\convert -colorspace sRGB -density 150 -alpha off file.pdf file.png`